# Nodemon takes a while to pick up nfs changes

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, nodemon, minikube

This may be configurable in the nfs share or within nodemon, not sure...

Basically, for local dev of production k8s system using minikube with a persistent volume claim where the volume is a locally defined nfs share.

/etc/exports:

```
/path/to/nfs/share -alldirs -mapall=501:20 192.168.99.100
```

volume.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 15Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.99.1
    path: /path/to/nfs/share
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cr-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 15Gi
```

deployment.yml:

```
...(relevant section to mounting nfs share into container)
containers:
        - name: user
          image: image_name
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command:
          - npm
          args:
          - run
          - dev-start
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5600
          - containerPort: 5898
          volumeMounts:   # mount host directory for local development
            - mountPath: /usr/src/app
              name: user-mount
              subPath: backend/services/user
      volumes:
        - name: user-mount
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: cr-volume
...
```

The command here (npm run dev-start) is `. ./config/development/export-env.sh && DEBUG=user:* node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js --inspect=0.0.0.0:5898 --legacy-watch -L ./bin/www` as opposed to the prod npm start of `node ./bin/www`

So this all works and mimics a prod env locally and allows me to make changes on the local file system which make their way through to the containers and reload. My only issue is that nodemon generally won't pick up the changes to the file for between 30 to 60 seconds.

I don't know enough about nfs shares and how the daemon broadcasts changes or how nodemon with it's legacy-watch flag watches to know where to go from here, but I'd love to be able to fix this so changes are reloaded faster.

Comment: It feels like you are solving the wrong problem; the point of using docker is to be able to run the container on your machine, knowing that it will run the same in-cluster after you have finished _development_. So while I am sure there is some nfs+nodemon trickery one can give you, ensure that you aren't artificially making your life harder for no good reason

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel there is an argument for that, yes. But on the flip side having the infrastructure of the development environment as close to production as possible minimises the amount of regression testing I need to do. The deployed containers always get built and deployed with the code from the mounted folder once a PR is merged to master so I can be confident the code being changed and tested on the dev machine is what makes it into the container in prod.